# Searching a blob for a string

Tags: python, string, search

I have a base64 blob that I have loaded from a database. I have decoded it and now need to search it for a string. The blob can and does contain binary (non printable) bytes.

my code so far is simply

```
for row in cursor:
        b = base64.standard_b64decode(row[2])
```

So I need to find the position of string 'xyx' in b

Answer (score 0):

A "binary blob" is simply a string in python, so you can use [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index):

```
i= b.index('xyx')
```

i becomes the value of the 0-based index of the position of `'xyx'` in `b`. Note this will count bytes, not characters.

You can also use `str.find`, if you don't want to raise a exception in case `'xyx' not in b`

Comment: str.find('xyz') gives me UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Paul are you sure you're not trying to `decode` the string somewhere? `index` and `find` shouldn't try to decode characters. Try the following: `("".join(map(chr,range(256)))).index('\xff')`